# How to create a website that has a browsing window within it and allows me to have custom right-click menu on the browsing window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a website that has a window/frame within it that allows me to browse other websites. Also, I need a custom right-click menu within the browsing window/frame. I understand iframe solves the former but from my internet search it seems that the latter(custom right-click menu) cannot be achieved on iframe. Hence, is there any way that I can browse websites within a webpage and have custom right-click menu on it? Appreciate any help!

Comment: The only way to have right-click functionality added to the pages you are loading is by the pages you are loading being on the same domain, which greatly restricts your options. It isn't impossible, but it isn't going to be pretty and will require some server-side work. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Kevin B. Thanks for your reply. I've been finding ways to have custom right-click functionality on iframes but I have been unsuccessful so far. May I know what do you mean by pages loading being on the same domain? Does it mean websites hosted by me? I'm new at web programming hence I'm sorry if this is something simple.

Comment: Yes, websites coming from the same web address as the current page. For example, `http://www.foo.com/index.php` can access `http://www.foo.com/bar.php`, but not `http://www.bar.com/index.php`

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for explaining that to me. Hm, so does that mean there is no way that I can have right-click functionality on web pages that isn't hosted by me?

Comment: Correct. You would have to have a server-side proxy that gets the pages for you and modifies all of the anchor tags, and possibly the javascript. It would be a huge mess to deal with all the possibilities.

Comment: I see.. Okay I got it. Thanks Kevin B! Greatly appreciate your time to help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way would be to use AJAX and cross-site requests and loading the results in your webpage.
Note that this has a lot of limitations. First of all, you'll be able to query only sites that do allow cross-site requests or sites that have public API. 
That means that you won't get the actual page you're trying to get but just some plain data that you'll need to show somehow.

Comment: Hi Alexandernst. Thanks for your reply as well. I see. Okay I'll find out how to go about doing what you have suggested. It seems to be a solution that may work for the website that I need. Thanks!!

Comment: @doctor7891Lim If my answer helped you don't forget to click on the upvote (or maybe mark it as an answer)

Comment: Yea you did, and sorry about that as this is my first post. Thanks.